# AMP mail does not get rendered in corporate instance

Tags: amp-email

AMP mail does not get rendered within a corporate Google Workspace instance.

The same email is rendered properly in gmail domain and other Google Workspace domains (non corporate)
But for corporate domains it is not being rendered for one or another reason.

- we checked the setting of the user if dynamic mails are activated - OK
- we checked the OU if dynamic mails are activated - OK

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]? See also [ask].

Comment: Have you tried to use the debug widget? https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail/debugging-dynamic-email

Comment: Thanks Su Zhang! Once I enabled SPF all worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

1. I activated debugging mode : https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail/debugging-dynamic-email
2. Send AMP mail that does not get rendered
3. Receive error message.

In my case I had to enable SPF.

Answer (score 0):

To see the error why amp-emails is not shown, I used the Fallback Debugging Banner: https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail/debugging-dynamic-email

### What is the Fallback Debugging Banner and why do I need it?

Fallback Debugging Banner looks like this:

[image: AMP Fallback Debugging Banner]

if amp-emails is not displayed for some reason, then a similar error message appears(in gmail).

If you have registered your email address in Google (it is included in the white list) and you can freely send amp-emails from it, then in case of some error, the AMP-version of the message will not be displayed, but the Fallback version(regular email) will be displayed. In this case, you will not see an error message(Debugging Banner). That is, by default, this Fallback Debugging Banner is not displayed.

### How do I see the Fallback Debugging Banner?

You need to activate the standard amp-settings in gmail, namely:

> Navigate to Gmail Settings > General > Dynamic email and click
> Developer settings. This opens a dialog where you can whitelist an
> email address that can send you dynamic emails for testing purposes.

Read more here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail/testing-dynamic-email

**Total:** even if your email address is in the Google whitelist and you freely send amp-emails, in order to activate the debagging mod, you still need to add your email address in the gmail settings.
After adding the email to the gmail settings, do not forget to reload the page so that the Banner appears.